# In Visual Studio Code Angular commands work in Command Prompt Shell but not in Bash Shell

Tags: angular, bash, shell, cmd, angular-cli

Tried to create an Angular project this morning (ng new project-name) in the Visual Studio Code terminal, but I got command not found. Tried to check the version of Angular (ng -v) but again command not found. Someone at work helped me check some things. We discovered that the commands are not working in the VS Code terminal when I am using a Bash shell, but they are working when I use a Command Prompt shell. He is not sure why that is.

I really prefer Bash to Command Prompt, so I'm wondering if anyone knows why this would be occurring. I'll use Command Prompt in the meantime, but I want to go back to Bash as soon as I can.

Thanks!

Comment: Compare the active PATH between the two shells.

Comment: That said -- when you say "bash", is this something like cygwin or msys bash (both of which are compiled to native Windows executables and run in the same environment as other Windows applications), or WSU bash, or something else? How was it installed, and what provides it? (BTW, "git bash" is a distribution of msys bash).

Comment: It is git bash.

Comment: Great -- if it's git bash (better described as msys bash), you just need to fix the PATH. (We can't tell you how to do this unless you edit more details into the question, like the location of the executable and what your _current_ PATH is in each shell).

Comment: Thanks, but I need some clarification. Are we talking about a path involving Angular and Git Bash?

Comment: Compare `echo "$PATH"` in bash to `echo %PATH%` in `cmd.exe`. Presumably, the latter will include as one of its entries the location of `ng`, but the former will not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all who commented. What I ended up doing to solve my problem was to uninstall and reinstall node.js, npm and angular.